# How to override Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Flatrate?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, shipping

I need to override Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Flatrate through my custom module in magento 1.7.

Right now i have done this :

In my app/etc/modules/ i have the file "Namespace_Modulename.xml" with the code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config>
      <modules>
        <Namespace_Modulename>
           <active>true</active>
           <codePool>local</codePool>
       </Namespace_Modulename>
     </modules>
   </config>
```

In my app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/etc/ i have file "config.xml" with the code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <config>
    <modules>
       <Namespace_Modulename>
           <version>0.1.0</version>
       </Namespace_Modulename>
    </modules>
    <global>
     <models>
       <shipping>
         <rewrite>
              <carrier_flatrate>Namespace_Modulename_Model_Flatrate</carrier_flatrate>
         </rewrite>
       </shipping>
     </models>
   </global>
 </config>
```

In my app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/Model i have file "Flatrate.php" with the code:

```
  class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Flatrate
   extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
   implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
   {

   protected $_code = 'flatrate';


    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
        return false;
    }

    $freeBoxes = 0;
    if ($request->getAllItems()) {
        foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
            if ($item->getFreeShipping() && !$item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance()->isVirtual()) {
                $freeBoxes+=$item->getQty();
            }
        }
    }
    $this->setFreeBoxes($freeBoxes);

    $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
    if ($this->getConfigData('type') == 'O') { // per order
        $shippingPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');
    } elseif ($this->getConfigData('type') == 'I') { // per item
        $shippingPrice = '0.00';
        foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
            if (!$item->getFreeShipping()) {
                $productId = $item->getProduct()->getId();
                $productList = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('ship_price')
                    ->addIdFilter($productId);
                foreach($productList as $product) {
                    $quantity = $item->getQty();
                    if ($product->getShipPrice()) {
                        $shippingPrice+=$product->getShipPrice() * $quantity;
                    } else {
                        $shippingPrice+=$this->getConfigData('price') * $quantity;

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    } else {
        $shippingPrice = false;
    }

    $shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($shippingPrice);

    if ($shippingPrice !== false) {
        $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

        $method->setCarrier('flatrate');
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

        $method->setMethod('flatrate');
        $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

        if ($request->getFreeShipping() === true || $request->getPackageQty() == $this->getFreeBoxes()) {
            $shippingPrice = '0.00';
        }


        $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
        $method->setCost($shippingPrice);

        $result->append($method);
    }

    return $result;
}

public function getAllowedMethods()
{
    return array('flatrate'=>$this->getConfigData('name'));
}

}
```

But it's not working. May be i am missing something or doing anything wrong.
Please help,

Thanks in advance,
Sarvagya

Comment: It worked for me. Just copy/pasted the code you provided, I added an 'echo "OK";' on the first line in the model. Then I added a product to the cart and clicked on estimate shipping. I got the "OK" message. This means the file is loaded. Make sure you cleared the cache.

Comment: What @Marius said. You may also have another module already overwriting the model - this is one of Magento's main design flaws.

Comment: Check in Config > Advanced and see if your module is installed. Maybe you forgot the modules/etc/Namespace_Modulename.xml file

Comment: Did you found your problem? What was it? Please provide an answer an mark it as solution.

Comment: I have copied this exact code to my custom module. When I open the shopping cart page I get this error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function setStore() on a non-object in ../app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Shipping.php on line 421`

Answer (score 2):

First, clear cache and disable/refresh compilation. Then, rule out a competing rewrite. Deactivate your module and do the following on a page or with a workbench script:

```
$className = Mage::getConfig()->getModelClassName('shipping/carrier_flatrate');
echo $className;
$class = new $className;
echo get_class($class);
```

You should see `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Flatrate` two times. Anything other class name and you have a multi-rewrite to chain or otherwise resolve. If you do not see the classname a second time then there is an issue instantiating the class (likely because of autoloading issue). Reactivate your module and test the factory class name resolution as above, and you should see *your* `Flatrate` class name.

A final note - if you are rewriting the core `Flatrate` model, convention indicates that you should extend from it. It's academic in this case given that you are overriding everything in the parent class.